# Meaning of this passage?

Tags: translation, meaning

> しかしお師匠様の言う通りにしてみたんだが、本当に結構、いいとこまでイケたなぁ！
>   何でも、ツンツンと残虐を尽くした後に程よくヘタれてデレて見せると、好感度ってヤツが大幅アップするんだろー？

I think I understand half of the first sentence : "However, I did just as teacher told me but..." but I have no idea as to the rest.

> 本当に結構、いいとこまでイケたなぁ！

I guess this one means "It went well" ?
I can barely translate the other part, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「しかしお師匠様{ししょうさま}の言{い}う通{とお}りにしてみたんだが、本当{ほんとう}に結構{けっこう}、いいとこまでイケたなぁ！ 何{なん}でも、ツンツンと残虐{ざんぎゃく}を尽{つ}くした後{あと}に程{ほど}よくヘタれてデレて見{み}せると、好感度{こうかんど}ってヤツが大幅{おおはば}アップするんだろー？」

「いいとこまでイケた」 literally means "***I was able to go far enough***." That in turn means "***Something went adequately well***."  So. you got this one down.

「何でも」 here means "**I am told**", "**they say**", etc.  It ***does not*** mean "everything" or "anything".  ← Very important!  It often gets translated incorrectly in fan subs.

「ツンツンと」 means "***in a bad-tempered manner***"

「ヘタれる」 = "to get exhausted"

「デレる」 = "to act affectionate"

「好感度」 = "popularity rating"

「大幅アップする」 = "to skyrocket", "to increase by much"

My own (mostly literal) TL：

> "**However, I tried to do just as my dear master told me, and it actually went quite well!  They say that looking nicely exhausted and acting affectionate after doing all sorts of brutalities (in a bad-tempered manner) will make that thing called 'popularity rating' skyrocket for you, right?**"